# 301 Redirection for classic ASP website with IIS 6 server

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, asp.net

I am new in the SEO field. I have relaunched my old website to a new one, and my guess is I need to 301-redirect some/many of my old pages.

But I have deleted some of the pages from server which is not required in new website. That pages having good PageRank, so I'm thinking about 301 permanent redirect to relevant pages or home page. My website in classic ASP with IIS 6 server. Problem is that classic ASP does not understand a  *web.config* file.

In an Apache server we can create a *.htaccess* file and through which we can achieve redirection. So is there any option for classic ASP? I don't want those pages on server otherwise through properties I can set the redirection.

Answer (score 1):

A simplest option is to install an Apache ISAPI rewrite module on Server. It's get integrated with IIS6. You can place an .htaccess file (like Apache) in your website directory installed on server and just play with your redirects.

Check this option (Helicon): http://www.isapirewrite.com/ 
I think even the free version will suffice your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft site still has a lot of information on its site that can tell you how to do this, additionally you can also use a HTML redirect or JavaScript too.

> **SOURCE:** [Procedures](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true)
>
> To redirect requests to another Web site or directory
>
> 1. In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, right-click the Web site or directory you want to redirect, and click Properties.
> 2. Click the Home Directory, Virtual Directory, or Directory tab.
> 3. Under The content for this source should come from, click A redirection to a URL.
> 4. In the Redirect to box, type the URL of the destination directory or Web site. For example, to redirect all requests for files in the
>      Catalog directory to the NewCatalog directory, type /NewCatalog.
>
> To redirect all requests to a single file
>
> 1. In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, right-click the Web site or directory you want to redirect, and click Properties.
> 2. Click the Home Directory, Virtual Directory, or Directory tab.
> 3. Under The content for this source should come from, click A redirection to a URL.
> 4. In the Redirect to box, type the URL of the destination file.
> 5. Select the The exact URL entered above check box to prevent the Web server from appending the original file name to the destination URL.
>
> You can use wildcards and redirect variables in the destination URL to
>   precisely control how the original URL is translated into the
>   destination URL.
>
> You can also use the redirect method to redirect all requests for
>   files in a particular directory to a program. Generally, you should
>   pass any parameters from the original URL to the program, which you
>   can do by using redirect variables.
>
> To redirect requests to a program
>
> 1. In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, right-click the Web site or directory you want to redirect, and click Properties.
> 2. Click the Home Directory, Virtual Directory, or Directory tab.
> 3. Under The content for this source should come from, click A redirection to a URL.
>
> In the Redirect to box, type the URL of the program, including any
>   redirect variables needed to pass parameters to the program. For
>   example, to redirect all requests for scripts in a Scripts directory
>   to a logging program that records the requested URL and any parameters
>   passed with the URL, type `/Scripts/Logger.exe?URL=$V+PARAMS=$P. $V and
>   $P are redirect variables`.
>
> 1. Select the The exact URL entered above check box to prevent the Web server from appending the original file name to the destination URL.

Comment: I know how to did the redirection through IIS Server. But my question is if i want redirection for those pages which is not on server. is it possible for those pages to redirect on to relevant live pages of website. Actually those pages are still in google datbase.

Comment: Yes you should redirect old deleted pages to new relevant pages. Pages that are not relevant should be 404, or gone.

Comment: some of the Pages which are not relevant should be redirected to home page. But how to do this if pages are not in server?

Comment: No... You should 'NOT' redirect non-relevant pages anywhere, this includes the home page. A 404 page is completely normal and informs the user that the pages no longer exists. Redirecting to a page they do not intend with content is bad for user experience and SEO since Google does not like sites attempting to retain Juice, never-mind you pass on the old keywords to the front-page that can gimp your strong keywords.

Comment: ohkk... Thanks a lot Bybe.. but what about the relevant pages? how to do redirection for relevant pages which not on server?